# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error in FriendRequestsControlle#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to self-referential relationships and I am currently working through [this](https://dankim.io/mutual-friendship-rails/) tutorial for a mutual friendship model.

I have implemented the FriendRequest model and associated it to the User model:

**FriendRequest.rb**

```
class FriendRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :friend_requests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pending_friends, through: :friend_requests, source: :friend
```

I created a link on a user's profile page to create a new friend request:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Friend', friend_requests_path, method: :post %>
```

**friend_requests_controller.rb**

```
class FriendRequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_friend_request, except: [:index, :create]

  def create
    friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
    @friend_request = current_user.friend_requests.new(friend: friend)

    if @friend_request.save
      render :show, status: :created, location: @friend_request
    else
      render json: @friend_request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def set_friend_request
    @friend_request = FriendRequest.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

But it throws ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound `Couldn't find User with 'id'=`

Taking specific issue with the line: `friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])`

**Routes.rb**

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   ...
  resources :users

  resources :user_sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destory]
  get 'login' => 'user_sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy'

  get 'friends/index'
  get 'friends/destroy'
  resources :friend_requests

end
```

I've tried altering the params both in the `create` action and in the private method but I always get the same ActiveRecord error.

This is the log from the post request:

```
 Started POST "/friend_requests" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-28 19:36:16 -0400
Processing by FriendRequestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"BWRNktuMbSt6nNWDyloy+t7fwhyd8ITa/P4/7C0zmeCHyEPFQBVe9h2MpdCUC4Od4tjoC5Qg0x4Z6owf+29F9Q=="}
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 57ms (ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=):

app/controllers/friend_requests_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Comment: What's on your routes.rb file?

Comment: Good question, I have added it to the question.

Comment: Try passing the id you're expecting on the action, `friend_requests_path(id: some_friend_id)`. Make sure that this `.new(friend: friend)` works, shouldn't be `friend_id`?. Also, you should pass the object's id (since other way is deprecated :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you are expecting `params[:friend_id]` to be, but not passing it in the request.

Your link should be something like this:

```
link_to 'Add Friend', friend_requests_path(friend_id: 123), method: :post
```

Or like this:

```
button_to 'Add Friend', friend_requests_path, params: {friend_id: 123}
```